# How to copy audio file from iPhone's filesystem to asset library programmatically

Tags: iphone, audio

I have an audio file that I saved from stream into ~/Documents folder on iPhone.
I just wanted to make this file visible to user as (s)he can play it using iPod program or put that file into his/her song's album!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is not possible. Access to the iPod library is read-only at the moment.

Comment: is there any other way to make these saved files visible to user? OR i have to develop program for navigation and playing the saved song?!

Comment: You'll have to develop your own interface for displaying a list of these files.